# Running class Id in apex

Tags: apex, batch

Like we have `System` class method `currentPageReference()` to get the reference of current `Visualforce Page`. Do we have something similar to get the details of running `Apex Class`?

My requirement is to check status of previous instance of my Batch class when it ran last time. Depending on that I need to set certain attributes of current instance.

Currently I am storing Batch Class Id in custom setting and referring that while querying `AsyncApexJob` for status. Just wondering if there any other way.

Comment: the solution to this is to throw an exception and parse the stacktrace

Comment: @cropredy Eh you can query for it by name, which you should know since you're writing the dang thing.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - sorry; knee jerk response from some prior OP where they wanted to know what trigger was running

Comment: In short there is no direct way (system method)?

Comment: @karankhanna No. There is no OOB method to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the `Database.Batchable` interface methods all accept a `Database.BatchableContext` instance ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_database_batchablecontext.htm)) as a parameter. This object has a method called `getJobId()`.

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
{
    system.debug([SELECT ApexClassId FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :context.getJobId()]);
}
```

Otherwise, you can query for it. You can write a system wide cache or query for the specific record.

```
static Map<String, ApexClass> cache
{
    get
    { // Lazy Load Pattern
        if (cache == null)
        {
            cache = new Map<String, ApexClass>();
            for (ApexClass classInstance : [SELECT Name FROM ApexClass])
                classes.put(classInstance.Name, classInstance);
        }
        return cache;
    }
    private set;
}
static Id currentClassId
{
    get
    { // Lazy Load Pattern
        if (currentClassId == null)
        {
            currentClassId = [
                SELECT Id FROM ApexClass
                WHERE Name = '<current_class>'
                LIMIT 1
            ].Id;
        }
        return currentClassId;
    }
    private set;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian but I need to do this check in constructor of Batch class hence no context.

Comment: @karan Please explain ***why*** it has to be in the constructor.

Comment: I need to build my SOQL on the basis of that so it has to be before Start method.

Comment: You're still being excessively vague. What are you trying to do? Please edit your post to include a query, or something specific enough to give a concrete recommendation.

Comment: sorry, I was just avoiding to make my question complicated. I will add more details meanwhile let's assume it is usual Apex class (not implementing any interface) and within its method (custom or constructor) can I get the Id of that Apex class?

Comment: @karan have you tried querying the `ApexClass` object?